# How do I add leading zeroes to String.Format parameters?

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```cs
string textTransDate = String.Format("{0}-{1}-{2} {3}:{4}", DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, DateTime.Now.Hour, DateTime.Now.Minute);
```

I want to add leading zeroes to the month and day parameters if they are less than 10, how would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
string textTransDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
```

More info here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Answer (score 3):

```
String.Format(@"{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH\:mm}", DateTime.Now);
```

The escape character \: ensures you will get a literal colon separator rather than a culture-specific time separator, to match your original code.  See [Custom Date and Time format strings in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).

To get leading zeroes for numeric arguments, look at [Custom Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx):

```
String.Format("{0:0000}-{1:00}-{2:00} {3:00}:{4:00}", DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, DateTime.Now.Hour, DateTime.Now.Minute);
```

or even [Standard Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx):

```
String.Format("{0:D4}-{1:D2}-{2:D2} {3:D2}:{4:D2}", DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, DateTime.Now.Hour, DateTime.Now.Minute);
```

Comment: You need to either double the `\` or use a verbatim string literal though. Or put it in single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

`D2` format adds leading zeros if needed.

```
String.Format("{0}-{1:D2}-{2:D2} {3}:{4}", DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, DateTime.Now.Hour, DateTime.Now.Minute);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
string textTransDate = String.Format("{0}-{1:00}-{2} {3}:{4}", DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, DateTime.Now.Hour, DateTime.Now.Minute);
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this work:

```
string textTransDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yy-MM-hh:mm");
```